# How to access a variable from a angular directive?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

This directive is assigned to an image and it's using an jQuery plugin called Cropper. How can I get in HTML or in another angular controller the dynamic variable **width** and **height** of the element: `e.width` or `e.height`

```
.directive( "imgcrop", [function ($scope, $controller) {
      return {
          restrict: "A",
          scope: {
            proposal : "="
          },
          transclude: true,
          replace: true,
          link    : function ( $scope, $el, $attr ) {
              $attr.$observe( "src", function ( src ) {
                          jQuery( '#cropImage' ).cropper('destroy');
                          jQuery( '#cropImage' ).cropper( {
                              viewMode        : 0,
                              zoomable        : false,
                              preview: ".extra-preview",
                              dragMode        : 'crop',
                              guides          : true,
                              highlight       : true,
                              cropBoxMovable  : true,
                              cropBoxResizable: true,
                              crop            : function ( e ) {
                                  // Output the result data for cropping image.
                                  console.log( e.width );
                                  console.log( e.height );
                                  }
                          } );

              } );
          }
      }
    } ] );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setup a scope binding which you can use to pass the width and height back to the controller.

```
    .directive( "imgcrop", [function ($scope, $controller) {
          return {
              restrict: "A",
              scope: {
                proposal : "="
                , croppedWidth: '='
                , croppedHeight: '='
              },
              transclude: true,
              replace: true,
              link    : function ( $scope, $el, $attr ) {
                  $attr.$observe( "src", function ( src ) {
                      jQuery( '#cropImage' ).cropper('destroy');
                      jQuery( '#cropImage' ).cropper( {
                          viewMode        : 0,
                          zoomable        : false,
                          preview: ".extra-preview",
                          dragMode        : 'crop',
                          guides          : true,
                          highlight       : true,
                          cropBoxMovable  : true,
                          cropBoxResizable: true,
                          crop            : function ( e ) {
                              // Output the result data for cropping image.
                              $scope.croppedWidth = e.width;
                              $scope.croppedHeight = e.height;
                          }
                      } );
                  } );
              }
          }
    } ] );
```

Then on your image:

```
<img imgcrop croppedWidth="vm.width" croppedHeight="vm.height">
```

Comment: Thank you kicken, but how can I display it in the image or adding it in another controller? what is vm.width?

Comment: `vm.width` and `vm.height` are references to properties on the controller's scope.  The directive will assign the width and height to whatever scope property you specify there.

Comment: I pretty new to angular directives, but somehow I understand your technique. The only problem for me is that I don't know how to display them in HTML ? That's the simplest reason I want to use this properties.

Comment: So as far as I understood you can use this in the directive's controller, but how can you use it in an external controller?